# Удаление символа из ng-model перед отправкой запроса к api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, строки

Пишу свое первое приложение на angularJS, приложение делает запросы к api Instagram и возвращает ответ в представление в соответствии с введенным в input хештегом. Соответственно есть input:

```
<input class="form__input" ng-model="tag1">
```

В контроллере ему присваивается значение по умолчанию:

```
$scope.tag1 = "nature";
```

При запуске приложение сразу делает запрос к api и выводит результаты в представление. Значение хештега добавляется в url по которому происходит запрос, и здесь есть интересный момент - значение тега **НЕ ДОЛЖНО** содержать символ **#**, иначе в ответе придет только брань и ругань. То есть если вводить только слова, все работает прекрасно, но мы все привыкли что # является неотъемлемой часть любого хештега, поэтому хочется реализовать возможность разрешать пользователю вводить # и просто не отправлять этот символ на сервер. Вот тут то у меня и возникла проблема. Запрос к api вынесен в отдельный модуль:

```
angular.module('requestToApi', [])
  .constant('clientID', 'myClientID')
  .factory('getResponseApi', function(clientID, $http) {
    return {
      request: function (tag) {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent',
          params: {access_token: clientID}
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

Функция принимает параметр `tag`, в качестве аргумента при вызове ей передается `$scope.tag1`, все работает как надо. Пробовал использовать стандартные методы js для строк, проверять равен ли первый символ строки символу #, если да то удалять первый символ, но если я добавляю в функцию условие проверки,

```
angular.module('requestToApi', [])
  .constant('clientID', 'myClientID')
  .factory('getResponseApi', function(clientID, $http) {
    return {
      request: function (tag) {
        if (tag.charAt(0) === '#') {
          tag.replace(/^#/, '');
        }
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent',
          params: {access_token: clientID}
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

то получаю стандартную ругань на некорректный запрос, условие просто игнорируется. Что я делаю не так? Можно ли вообще применять стандартные методы js для работы со строками, числами к ангуляровским моделям? Возможно это реализуется совсем по другому, с помощью фильтров, например, но если использовать фильтры, то получается что мы не даем пользователю возможности ввести символ? Подскажите как быть, что лучше использовать в данной ситуации?

Comment: `replace` **НЕ МЕНЯЕТ** исходную строку

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу следующим образом:

```
angular.module('requestToApi', [])
  .constant('clientID', 'myClientID')
  .factory('getResponseApi', function(clientID, $http) {
    return {
      request: function (tag) {
        let convertedTag;

        tag.charAt(0) === '#' ? convertedTag = tag.slice(1) 
          : convertedTag = tag;

        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + convertedTag + '/media/recent',
          params: {access_token: clientID}
        })
      }
    }
  });
```

Возможно будет кому ни будь полезно.

Comment: тернарный оператор это уже выражение, следовательно его значение можно присвоить: `let convertedTag = tag.charAt(0) === '#' ? tag.slice(1) : tag;`

Comment: Да, так лучше, спасибо